# How to use loop in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hi I am making a bot to create a leaderboard , here is the code

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def on(ctx):
    await ctx.send("How many total teams are there?")
    t = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
    totalteam = 0
    while totalteam <= t:
        await ctx.send("Enter team name :")
        teamname1 = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How many kills did they get?")
        firstnum1 = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How much Position points did they score?")
        secondnum1 = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
        totalteam -=1
    await ctx.channel.send("**__Today's Result:__**")
    await ctx.channel.send("Format: Team Name/Kills/Position Points/Total Points")
    await ctx.send(f"{teamname1} | {firstnum1} | {secondnum1} = {firstnum1+secondnum1}")
```

This command enables the user to choose for how many teams he want to create the leaderboard.
The loop for total teams work but I want something that shows the result in loop too.
I want that it should send total points of every team the user entered. Now it just sends the points of first entry.

Comment: What do you want it to output ? Put in  expected result?

Comment: What is the function `get_input_of_type`?

Comment: sum = 0 above while loop than sum=sum+secondnum1+kills would work and than output sum.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cool idea to create a team **Class** that had certain attributes like team name, number of kills, position points, etc. You could then add all the teams to an array or list, and then loop through them to create leader boards and other helpful features.

I recommend this YouTube video that details perfectly how Object Oriented Programming (OOP) in Python works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MikphENIrOo

Your team class might look something like this:

```
Class Team:
 def __init__(name, kills, points):
  self.name = name
  self.kills = kills
  self.points = points
```

Then you might have a list

```
teams = []
```

and you could append to that list for every number of teams the user wants

```
teams.append(Team(BestTeam, 10, 50))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an embed to make is look nice. I added the two functions you should use.

[image]

```py
def check(ctx):
    return lambda m: m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel


async def get_input_of_type(func, ctx):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx))
            return func(msg.content)
        except ValueError:
            continue


@bot.command()
async def on(ctx):
    await ctx.send("How many total teams are there?")
    t = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="**__Today's Result:__**")
    
    for i in range(t):
        await ctx.send(f"Enter team {i+1} name :")
        teamname = await get_input_of_type(str, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How many kills did they get?")
        firstnum = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)
        await ctx.send("How much Position points did they score?")
        secondnum = await get_input_of_type(int, ctx)

        embed.add_field(name=teamname, value=f'Kills: {firstnum}\n Position: {secondnum}')

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```